# Send form data as traditional Post method with CHtml::ajaxLink

Tags: yii

The form can be send with `CHtml::ajaxLink` as traditional POST method if Browser JavaScript is disabled?

Or for this desired must be used `submitButton` with snippet `'return false;'` JavaScript on `submit` event?

My desired is: a `Link` for sending form data as `Ajax` and traditional `Post` methods(traditional `Post` method for when browser JavaScript is disabled). is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a sort of fallback:

```
<!-- at start Hide the ajax link -->
<style type="text/css">
    #ajax-form {display: none;}
</style>
```

Then you put your div that contains the ajax form:

```
<div id="ajax-form">
    <?php  //Ajax code ?>
</div>
```

And the code that'll be executed if javascript is not enabled:

```
<noscript>
    <?php echo
    CHtml::beginForm('', 'post') . 
    CHtml::hiddenField('field', $model->id) .
    CHtml::submitButton('button') . 
    CHtml::endForm(); 
    ?>
</noscript>
```

And at the end you include the javascript that'll show the ajax div if javascript is enabled:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<style type="text/css">#ajax-form {display: inline;}</style>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there other way for do it?

Comment: hum I havn't found any other solution, this is why I've done it this way.

Comment: In fact, there is no solution with Yii, like setting `htmlOption` in `CHtml::ajaxLink`. that's right?

Comment: `htmlOption` let you add some options like an id for the link, a class, a target, ... The are also some special yii options that you can see here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail